# Javascript "end of week" date calculations?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Is there a helper library out there for doing these types of date calculations like in Rails?

```
Date.today.end_of_week
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no build in function, but you could define your own:

```
Date.prototype.endOfWeek = function(){
  return new Date( 
      this.getFullYear(), 
      this.getMonth(), 
      this.getDate() + 6 - this.getDay() 
  );
};

var now = new Date();

// returns next saturday; and returns saturday if it is saturday today.
console.log( now.endOfWeek() );
```

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**
[DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/)

I'm not sure what you consider "end of week", assuming it's Saturday, I believe

```
Date.parse('saturday');
```

will give you the next Saturday (or today, if today is Saturday)

Answer (score 1):

I built a time library that have some of these methods, [time.js](http://ditrw.com/time-dot-js/).

It doesn't have all the stuff DateJS have, which can be good and bad depending on how you look at it ;)

If I was able to I'd reproduce the code needed to take any Date instance to end of the current week, but it's a little bit involved. Should be easy enough to figure out the basics by looking at [the code](https://github.com/augustl/time.js/blob/master/time.js), though.

Comment: +1 for the ref to your excellent library, small, simple to use and has just the essentials for everyday tasks.